# HttpAsyncTask can't access localhost

Tags: android, localhost, httpclient, emulation

i have this code :

```
public class Connexion extends Activity {

    EditText etResponse;
    TextView tvIsConnected;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);

        // get reference to the views
        etResponse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResponse);
        tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);

        // check if you are connected or not
        if(isConnected()){
            tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
        }
        else{
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
        }

        // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute("https://10.0.2.2:29422/service/MBBS/TWVpblRlc3RJRGRlc2dlcmFldHMxNTA3MjAxNjE0MTgyMTMyMC41MzQzMjk2NDM0ODM2NDY2/customer");
    }

    public static String GET(String url){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return GET(urls[0]);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            etResponse.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

i have try to exceute by emulator this adresse:"https://10.0.2.2:29422/service/MBBS/TWVpblRlc3RJRGRlc2dlcmFldHMxNTA3MjAxNjE0MTgyMTMyMC41MzQzMjk2NDM0ODM2NDY2/customer"

i can't access but with the same adresse by my laptop :
"https://localhost:29422/service/MBBS/TWVpblRlc3RJRGRlc2dlcmFldHMxNTA3MjAxNjE0MTgyMTMyMC41MzQzMjk2NDM0ODM2NDY2/customer" this work

any idee?

Comment: Give your machine IP instead of localhost. It will work.

Comment: when i would work with emulator this localhost adresse is :10.0.2.2 or?

Comment: It is `10.0.2.2` but what is the error message?

Comment: why i can't access with 10.0.2.2 ??

Comment: @ange What is the error message in logcat? If you cannot access it, there should be exception(s).

Comment: @Joshua no error only  E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f5d230a1690

Comment: @ange Not that one. How about using emulator browser to access it?

Comment: @Joshua ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 0):

Since my reputation is not +50 I am writing here.

Emulator works on the same pc as the server is running hence can access localhost
If you want to access server running on Localhost in your mobile device, you will have to:

-> If your device and system are on the same LAN you can user the IP address of the system

If you don't know the IP address of your system use:

```
ipconfig        //Windows
ifconfig        //Linux
```

OR

-> Assign a static IP to the system running the server

Comment: He is running emulator. Therefore, the ip for localhost is `10.0.2.2`.